# AngularJs. $location service. Url modification

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose, I have follwing code with AngularJs:

```
 angular.module('somename', []).
         config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                when('/test/:userid', { controller: TestDataCtrl }).
                when('/users/:userid', {controller: UserDataCtrl}).
                otherwise({redirectTo: '/index.html'});
                $location.path('/newValue')
                });
```

But this fragment throws ReferenceError: $location is not defined from archivarius. Ok, no problem. I added third parameter $location to the function and got error -- Unknown provider: $location from archivarius.

So, how can I get instance of $location service?

In other words, I have some ugly url like:

```
http://localhost:7000/myservice/1?html=true#/index
```

and my routes above doesn't work, because it is supposed
that service url looks like

```
http://localhost:7000/myservice/#/index          
   or
http://localhost:7000/myservice/index
```

But because of my internal redirect logic of REST  service I came up with 
a little bit confusing url for AngularJs and I need to change it without page reload.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need `$location.path('/newValue')`?

Comment: To change the url. I took it from examples...

Comment: You don't change the location in the config. You'd normally do that in a controller where the $location is injected.

Comment: @Sharondio: and how can I execute controller on page load (or after page load)? Sorry for such questions -- I'm newbie to AngularJs and javascript.

Comment: The controller is loaded every time the route changes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `$location' object to you config unanimous function:

```
config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $location)
```

Hope it helps